# How can I find a decryption algorithm having a set of string inputs and hex outputs?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have a set of inputs and outputs to a encryption algorithm (black box) that given an ascii string returns a hex string.
How could I manage to find the decryption algorithm ?

I leave some examples:

- a -> 98 A1
- aa -> 98 40 9D
- aaa -> 98 40 7C F6
- (space) -> 59 60
- / -> 56 6F
- 0 -> 49 70
- 1 -> 48 71
- 2 -> 4B 72
- 3 -> 4A 73

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think that this is a well-known encryption algorithm, but you can break it yourself quite easily. Look at the encryption results for single characters: the second byte is ascii code of the plaintext + 0x40. Try to compare the hex output with the ascii codes of the letters.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one as well, but the double and triple characters are trickier.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @AndrewMorozko I tried that, I got to some rules but it gets trickier when the string to decode gets larger. 
I want to know wich methods or strategies are available rather than just manually do it.

Comment: @JCFortunatti You could try searching https://www.dcode.fr, they have a large database of simple ciphers. You could also try reverse-engineering the binary, if you have it. It’s not a blackbox if it is running on your machine;)